# colorbox (jquery) load images when slideshow clicked

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have colorbox on my website. When I click on image slideshow starts with 20 images. Until my slideshow is running, there is a chance that in my folder with images new images are uploaded via ftp. How can I make a function which "reloads" or loads new images only to my slideshow when last image is shown?
Explanation: Slideshow runs and it shows 1/20, 2/20, ... 20/20 and now it should automatically reload or add new images which comes to server until slideshow was running (so there can be 5 more new images upt to 25/25). So I need to add 5 more images to slideshow and show these images in slideshow as well.

Hope you understand what I mean. Thank you.